# Set sudo timestamp when logging in

Tags: sudo, login, password

I want to set the sudo timestamp when logging in. So that I don't have to type password again, to use `sudo` (if done shortly after login).

Can I configure system using `PAM` or sudo configuration or something else so that when user logs in, they get the right to run `sudo` without typing any password for a short period?

Practical example,

1. Connect using SSH
2. Want to administer; type `sudo -s` (policy is that all administrative tasks are done with the same user)
3. No need to type password again because user has just logged in with his password

[I know sudo can be configured to have cached information on whether a user is allowed to execute `sudo` again without the password being requested](https://askubuntu.com/a/190320/255736). But this question is not that.

Comment: As an aside, you really don't need `sudo su`. Perhaps you meant `sudo -s` or maybe `sudo -i`?

Comment: So setting the time stamp on login. And it timing out as normal. Is that correct?

Comment: @roaima `sudo -s` right.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Right. Basically, if you just logged in, you have already been tested who is who so no need to test again for a short time period. Just like other `sudo` calls are cached.

Comment: The "sudo timestamp" is kept in a `root` accessible directory,  you need `sudo` to set it.

Comment: @waltinator That's not a problem. PAM runs as root and I can always setup a pam_script module to run a script that achieves that. I would only need to know what to run and know who can use sudo so I don't allow everybody to just call sudo